# Ternary operator in while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, conditional-operator

In this scenario, why is it that the output for i is 1 and not 0, since the while loop decrements the value for i two times from it's original value i=2?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i=2,j=2;
    while(i+1?--i:j++)
         printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because your complicated ternary operator can be reduced to

```
while(--i)
```

Explanation.

`i+1 == 3`, `--i` executes. `i == 1` so the body of while loop executes (prints `1`). now `i+1 == 2`, `--i` executes, `i == 0` which is false in C and body of the while loop is being skipped.

`i` is decremneted twice - but `printf` executed only 1 time.

You can test it adding one more `printf`:

```
int main(){
    int i=2,j=2;
    while(i+1?--i:j++)
         printf("%d\n",i);
    printf("%d\n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

and the result will be as expected

```
1
0
```